# Upgraded Spring MVC portlet throws org.w3c.dom.Document not found exception when deployed in Liferay 7

Tags: spring-mvc, liferay-7

I'm upgrading Liferay portal from 6.2 to 7. I have upgraded spring MVC portlet so that it can deploy in Liferay 7 server. Resolved some of the exceptions by excluding xercesImpl.jar and xml-apis.jar as mentioned below.

java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory: Provider org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl not a subtype

When fixed and deployed again, then occurred exception org.w3c.dom.Document not found. It should be recognized from Java JRE's rt.jar but it's not.

Environment:
Windows Laptop
JDK 1.8_181
Liferay 7.0-sp8
HSQL

Comment: If you could provide a github link to the simplest code with which the issue is reproducible, I would be happy to assist you further